# When is the group algebra a product of local rings up to Morita equivalence?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

Let $KG$ be the group algebra of a finite group $G$ over a field of characteristic $p$.

> Question 1: Is there a characterisation when $KG$ is Morita equivalent to a product of local rings?

This should be true for example when $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.

> Question 2: Is there a description of the group algebra when $G$ has order $p^n q$ for primes $p<q$ in terms of its $p$-Sylowsubgroup $P$ (if it helps, assume $p=2$)? Maybe even quiver and relations of $G$ are known in terms of quiver and relations of $KP$?

Comment: If the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal in $G$ then the structure of the group algebra of $G$ in Q2 is given in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82536627.pdf .

Answer (score 6):

At least if the field is algebraically closed (or sufficiently large), a finite group has a normal $p$-complement if and only if its principal block is local. For example, this is Corollary 6.13 of

*Navarro, Gabriel*, Characters and blocks of finite groups, London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series. 250. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. x, 287 p. (1998). [ZBL0903.20004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0903.20004).